# Failed to modify the attributes of a queue pair when using openmpi

Tags: python, mpi

I ran into an mpi exception today when just calling mpirun, and it was never seen before. The exception is:

---

```
Failed to modify the attributes of a queue pair (QP):

Hostname: nmyjs_104_22
Mask for QP attributes to be modified: 113
Error:    Invalid argument
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI has detected that there are UD-capable Verbs devices on your
system, but none of them were able to be setup properly.  This may
indicate a problem on this system.

You job will continue, but Open MPI will ignore the "ud" oob component
in this run.

Hostname: nmyjs_104_22
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun could not find anything to do.

It is possible that you forgot to specify how many processes to run
via the "-np" argument.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output seems to mean that openmpi will run anyway. But my codes fails even just mpirun a simple command in this situation.

For example, `mpirun -np 1 echo "hello world"`, the exception is:

```
[@nmyjs_104_22 ~]$ mpirun -np 1 echo "hello"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to modify the attributes of a queue pair (QP):

Hostname: nmyjs_104_22
Mask for QP attributes to be modified: 113
Error:    Invalid argument
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI has detected that there are UD-capable Verbs devices on your
system, but none of them were able to be setup properly.  This may
indicate a problem on this system.

You job will continue, but Open MPI will ignore the "ud" oob component
in this run.

Hostname: nmyjs_104_22
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] *** Process received signal ***
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] Failing at address: 0x100000007
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3da4a0f710]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 1] /usr/local/lib/libopen-rte.so.20(orte_rml_send_callback+0x13)[0x7f59b87904e3]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 2] /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so(+0x1e34)[0x7f59b4ccee34]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 3] /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.so.20(opal_libevent2022_event_base_loop+0xbf1)[0x7f59b84a7ec1]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 4] mpirun[0x404b41]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 5] mpirun[0x403466]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 6] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3da461ed5d]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] [ 7] mpirun[0x403359]
[nmyjs_104_22:21719] *** End of error message ***
```

I googled it but got no luck. What I did today is to update openmpi from 2.0.2 to 2.1.0, which located in [this page](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/). I also reverted the openmpi to 2.0.2, still got this error. Hope somebody could help.

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably have more luck asking in the openmpi mailing list. Also notice that at the end of exception "asks" you to check whether you omitted -np.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I've also asked in `openmpi` mailing list. Hope they can help me with it. And the `-np` should not be a problem, because it's just an unnecessary argument for the simple test.

Comment: What is your `mpirun` command?! You seem to forgot to include some of the *required* parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but It should not a problem. Even if I use the command like: `mpirun -np 1 python -c "print('hello world')"`, there still be the exception